# Amazon S3 secure bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Sorry if this is the incorrect place to ask.

Is they a way to secure a AWS S3 bucket so direct access to the files is denied but signed access is allowed?

I am new to all this, I have looked at Policies and Permissions but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this steps for Amazon S3 secure bucket:

1. Give only full permission to owner only for all the objects in that bucket. You can try any third party tool like bucket Explorer to set [ACL on all the objects exist in Amazon S3 Bucket](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-update-amazon-s3-acl-in-batch-on-bucket.html).
2. Just make sure that there is no policy set on that Bucket as Bucket policy has higher priority then ACL.
3. [Generate there signed url](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-files.html#signedurl) and provide the users, if you want that user can access your files.

[Disclosure : [Bucket Explorer]](http://www.bucketexplorer.com)

Comment: Thanks Rohak, I eventually figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the ACLs for all the objects in the bucket and remove access for the `Everyone` user. You will also need to make sure that you don't have a bucket policy that overrides those ACLs and allows public access to your files.

These links should help:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingPermissionsonanObject.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html

For the bucket policy, you need to look for any statements that give anonymous access to your objects and change those. These will contain a `"Principal": { "AWS": "*" }` in the policy.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: S3 buckets are secure by default. You can open them up by:

1) setting the ACL on the bucket to "public read"

2) setting a policy for "everyone" via `Principal: {AWS: * }`

3) Uploading an object with ACL of "public read"

3) setting the ACL on an object to "public read" after upload